# Cannot add sharepoint reference

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I try to upload my file from local drive to sharepoint server, but I couldn't add Microsoft.SharePoint to my reference. sharepoint foundation already installed. And I still got error

The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am pretty sure the reference was already add, but after build the solution, it just keeps getting errors.

Can anyone provide the solution? thx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Visual Studio and SharePoint foundation are on same machine,

verify that the dll you are referencing is Microsoft.SharePoint.dll v14 and it's picked

```
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\ISAPI
```

directory on your SharePoint server.